# Mounting a tv on a sandstone wall

Tags: mounting, bedroom, television

I just bought a new TV for my bedroom, and I want to mount it on the wall. The only problem is that the walls of the house are made of sandstone and if i mount it directly to it, it won't hold. I was thinking of making a hole, filling it with mortar, and inserting an anchor. Will this hold ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sandstone walls, but if you are worried about anchors not holding, I would think mortar would be just a bigger thing to fail.  Consider a freestanding support that doesn't rely on the wall, like the suggestion here: [Need help mounting a TV to the wall](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/113652/28390).

Comment: Please clarify what exactly sandstone walls are. Solid blocks? Sheet stone veneer? Stone tile?